# How to change column size of RecycleView when load native ads in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, admob

I want to implement RecycleView like attach image link. When native ad load at time change number of column of RecycleView. I have tried with admobadapter but it's load native ads but not change the RecycleView column size.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjxN8.png

If any one have solution for this then help me...

Thanks